# gparted on 19.04 does not show gui

Tags: gparted

I installed `gparted` from the Ubuntu repository. When trying to use it, I was asked to authenticate, but nothing displayed after that. I am using the NVIDIA version 418 driver as recommended by the `software and updates` program. `Gparted` remains running with nothing displayed.
This problem only appears on Ubuntu 19.04 after a software upgrade from 18.04. It does not appear on a fresh install of Ubuntu 19.04.

Comment: try `sudo killall gparted gpartedbin`

Comment: Did you run it from command line? Try first `sudo -i` then `gparted`...

Comment: Are you seeing a 'cannot open display :0' error? Try "xhost +" before running gparted.

Comment: @ Wayne Vosberg No messages were generated after the authentication dialogue was processed.

Comment: gparted does not run on wayland the last time I tested it. Please, log out your current session. Then, in the login screen click on the small gear icon next to the password field and select just `Ubuntu` or `Gnome` if available, but not `Ubuntu on wayland` and login. Try gparted now and it should run as expected.

Comment: @Raffa - I am running 19.04 with gparted 0.32.0-1ubuntu1 on wayland with no issues.